# How can I make a comma disappear if it's at the end of the line?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to have a comma on my web page set up such that, if the text it is in the middle of gets split such that the comma appears at the end of the line, the comma disappears. How can I do this?

---

Why would I want such a strange thing, you ask? I have a street address that I want to look like this on wide viewports:

> 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC 20500

...but on narrower viewports, I want it to look like this:

> 1600 Pennsylvania Ave
>   Washington, DC 20500

I already got it to always split the text at the correct point using `white-space: nowrap;`, but I don't know how to prevent that pesky comma from showing up at the end of the first line of the address.

Comment: this sounds more like something you would need Javascript or Jquery for, rather than CSS.

Comment: @RickHitchcock If there's a CSS-only solution that'd be preferrable, but I'll settle for a JS fix.

Comment: CSS can't detect where text will break so JS would be required or a change in the HTML structure.

Comment: Impractical, but I bet you could use a custom font to replace the "soft hyphen" (Unicode U+00AD) character with one that looks like a comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap each part of the address in a `<span>`. Then use a pseudo element to add the comma on larger screens.

```css
.address span {
    display: block;
}    
@media( min-width: 480px ) {
    .address span {
        display: inline;
    }
    .address span:after {
        content: ', ';
    }
    .address span:last-of-type:after {
        content: '';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="address">
    <span>1600 Pennsylvania Ave</span>
    <span>Washington, DC 20500</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bukwpthg/

#### Edit

Incorporated *Paulie_D's* suggestion. CSS now supports multiple lines/spans instead of two. It will add a comma for every `<span>` except for the last one.

```html
<div class="address">
    <span>1600 Pennsylvania Ave</span>
    <span>Washington</span>
    <span>DC 20500</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bukwpthg/3/

Comment: Ah of course, why didn't I think of that? I did slightly change this so that the comma was in a span that was `display:none` by default, but `display:inline` inside the media query (I want the comma to be selectable for copy-paste purposes, which isn't possible with the `:after` content), but otherwise this is exactly what I went with. Muchos gracias!

Comment: I like this solution!

Comment: Might I suggest an alternative....that you put a comma after *every* span **except** the last one...then it would work for multiline addresses - http://jsfiddle.net/bukwpthg/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D great idea, added to answer!

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kudude/2/edit?html,css,output)***

```
1600 Pennsylvania Ave<span class="sm-break">,</span> Washington, DC 20500
```

```
@media (max-width: 480px)  {
  .sm-break{ display:block; height:0; visibility:hidden; }
}
```

wrap your comma into a `span`, set it to `block` and `hidden` for smaller screens

Comment: The problem is that my address doesn't always break across two lines on the small viewport.